# Count Number of Images on Directory via AJAX and Update JS Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the total number of images inside a directory containing 23 images. I succesfully got the total number via AJAX but I can't pass the number to JS. What am I doing wrong?

```
    var url = 'content/images/'; 
    var imgcount = 0; 

    function countImages(){
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                        if( val.match(/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/) ) {                   
                            imgcount++;
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('imgcount: '+imgcount); // returns 23
            }
        });
    }
    countImages();
    
    console.log('imgcount: '+imgcount); // returns 0
```

Comment: It’s async, so the Ajax part will happen after all the code currently being executed finishes (including your final console log).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Thank you James. I've read several posts related to this issue I'm having, neither of them were as eloquently adn thoroughly written as this one, which I haven't seen before. I'll see if it helps me understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: It’s probably the most asked-about topic on SO.  Another solid resource is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)